# how can i do a math in an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, math

I want to calculate the `qty * price` in `totalPrice`  and it gives me "qty is not defined", how can i do it?

```
let products = [
{
    title: "Sunglasses",
    imgURL: "images/Products/sunglasses.jpg",
    desc: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut nulla adipisci fugiat pariatur recusandae repudiandae fuga molestias doloremque itaque obcaecati.",
    price:80,
    qty:1,
    totalPrice: qty * price,
    id: 1
}]
```

it supposed to be a shopping cart so the `qty` changes and i want the `totalPrice` to be in the object because i suppose to put every `totalPrice` of the products in cart together to get the total price of the whole cart

Comment: Why not `totalPrice: 1*80`?

Comment: where does the `80` and the `1`  come from? ... it makes no sense to have a field such as `totalPrice` in a database record ... it only takes up storage space and can be easily calculated using a query

Comment: @MrUpsidown it supposed to be a shopping cart so the `qty` changes and i want the `totalPrice` to be in the object because i suppose to put every `totalPrice` of the products in cart together to get the total price of the cart

Comment: You got two answers so far. Any feed-back to them?

Comment: *"...put every totalPrice of the products in cart together to get the total price of the whole cart"* how about `const totalCart = products.reduce((sum, {qty, price}) => sum + qty * price, 0);` That's how simple you can get the total price for the cart without the need for these properties on the object. Espetially with something so dynamic as a shopping cart, I'd avoid storing redundant data. It's too simple that `qty*price` and `totalPrice` get out of sync, and imo. overkill to use a getter for something that trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const products = [
  {
    title: "Sunglasses",
    imgURL: "images/Products/sunglasses.jpg",
    desc: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut nulla adipisci fugiat pariatur recusandae repudiandae fuga molestias doloremque itaque obcaecati.",
    price:80,
    qty:1,
    id: 1
  }
];

const res = products.map(product => 
  ({ ...product, totalPrice: product.qty * product.price })
);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are referencing *variables* (which don't exist), not *properties*.

There are a few ways to handle this. For instance, you could add the total price in a second step:

```
let products = [
{
    title: "Sunglasses",
    imgURL: "images/Products/sunglasses.jpg",
    desc: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut nulla adipisci fugiat pariatur recusandae repudiandae fuga molestias doloremque itaque obcaecati.",
    price:80,
    qty:1,
    id: 1
}]

for (let product of products) product.totalPrice = product.qty * product.price;
```

Or you can have it calculated dynamically with a getter:

```
let products = [
{
    title: "Sunglasses",
    imgURL: "images/Products/sunglasses.jpg",
    desc: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut nulla adipisci fugiat pariatur recusandae repudiandae fuga molestias doloremque itaque obcaecati.",
    price:80,
    qty:1,
    get totalPrice() { return this.qty * this.price },
    id: 1
}]
```